# How to Use Sitecore Ship with TDS

Tags: sitecore, tds

Could be a basic question but i am not able to find any manual.  I installed Sitecore ship via nuget package
The Sitecore ship is installed. I have a update package created by TDS. i now need to install this. 
When I hit the url

> "http://mysite/services/package/install/fileupload"

i get a **404.**
I am not sure what to do next. 
where do i give the path of the package?

Am i missing anything else?

```
Sitecore version 8.1
S.ship version 0.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to issue a POST request to the `/services/package/install/fileupload` and pass it the location of an update package file to uload to the server.

An Example would be something like

```
POST /services/package/install/fileupload HTTP/1.1
Host: shiptester
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="path"; filename="package.update"
Content-Type: 


----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

You can reference the [Sitecore.Ship Wiki](https://github.com/kevinobee/Sitecore.Ship/wiki) for additional options and feature uses.

Comment: Thank you. Yes i figured that out. I was trying to hit the url directly from browser and hence the issue. i used postman to simulate the call.